# How can I exclude blank lines with awk?

Tags: awk, blank-line

### Question

How can I exclude lines starting with a space character, and that have nothing else on the line? With awk, I want to print the line `Need to print`, but it's also printing the blank line. How can I exclude it?

## Script: test.awk

```
$0 !~/^start|^#/ {
print "Result : %s",$0
}
```

## Data

```
# test

start
Need to print
```

## Result

```
Result : %s 
Result : %s Need to print
```

Comment: The 2 answers you have will behave differently when a line contains only blank chars - which solution you need depends on whether such a line should be considered a "blank line" or not for your purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use the *NF* Variable

You aren't really asking about lines that start with a space, you're asking about how to discard blank lines. Pragmatically speaking, blank lines have no fields, so you can use the built-in *NF* variable to discard lines which don't have at least one field. For example:

```
$ awk 'NF > 0 && !/^(start|#)/ {print "Result: " $0}' /tmp/corpus 
Result: Need to print
```

Comment: `NF > 0` can be replaced with `NF`.

Comment: @karakfa Possibly, as it works with BSD and GNU awk. However, I'm not sure how portable that is across all awks. Even if it's 100% portable, brevity never trumps clarity of intent. I always prefer my code to  be clear about comparisons, rather than using implicit comparisons that are difficult for future readers to reason about. YMMV. Nevertheless, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I agree in principle, but `awk 'NF'` is idiomatic awk to print non empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
awk '/^[^[:space:]]/{print "Result : " $0}'
```

The use of `[^[:space:]]` ensures that there is at least a single non space character in every line which get's printed.

Comment: The leading `^` in `/^[^[:space:]]/` means it would skip any lines that have indented non-space text. It's not 100% clear from the question since the sample input didn't include that case but that's usually not what people mean when they say they want to `exclude lines starting with a space character, and that have nothing else on the line`.